# How to record a transcript from python session

Tags: python, linux, bash, logging

I want to record an entire python session into a text file (users commands and their outputs together) for the user to easily see what was done during that interactive session.

A have a bash code using the command "`script`" from linux as follows:

```
script -c python3.6 user_session
```

The problem is that every keystroke is recorded on that file, including reverse search, cursor excursion, etc... Example:

[image: Polluted output from script command]

I begin writing a python script that filters out these characters, but the script is getting very complex and the amount of possibilities is too high.

One thing I noticed is that the "`cat`" command prints the output file correctly, but redirecting the output from the command to a file gives no good result. Same especial characters as before.

Is there any alternative to the "`script`" command or an easier way of getting rid of these characters?

Edit 1:

Ideally, the expected output would be the same as the "`cat`" command. Just as in the following picture:

[image: Expected result]

Comment: Can you add an expected output?

Comment: Expected output added.